# SF on R 3.5 can't find correct version of gdal

Tags: r, r-sf

I had the sf package installed and working on r 3.4.3 on Centos 7. It was complicated to get the right version of GDAL but it was working and I was able to use tidycensus to make maps.

However when I upgraded to R 3.5 and then attempted to upgrade or reinstall sf, I started getting this message:

> checking for gdal-config...
>
> /bin/gdal-config checking gdal-config usability... yes
>
> configure: GDAL: 1.11.4 checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... no
>
> configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0

However I definitely have GDAL 2 installed as evidenced by the fact that it was working before plus if I do  `gdalinfo --version`  I get

> GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20

I did read a lot of SO questions and discovered the RDGAL is compiled with the 1.11.4  version and I think that sf relies on that. However I have not found a way on Centos to force it to use GDAL 2.2.3.  I have removed and reinstalled rdgal and it didn't help, it always reinstalls with 1.1.

```
 rgdal::getGDALVersionInfo(str = "--version")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not totally sure if this was the whole solution but following the comments on [this page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203664387-rgdal-not-loading-in-Rstudio-server-but-loads-from-command-line) I did this:

```
R CMD INSTALL -l ~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1 
--configure-args='
--with-gdal-config path/to/software/dir/bin/gdal-config 
--with-proj-include path/to/software/dir/include 
--with-proj-lib path/to/software/dir/lib 
--with-proj-data path/to/software/dir/share/proj 
--with-data-copy=yes' rgdal
```

And it worked. I did other things in between that may have helped though.

Update:
Going through the same thing with an updated R to 3.6, I found that if I removed rgdal and reinstalled (with no special options) I was able to then install sf successfully.