# sf R package "is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0" after installing gdal 2.3 from conda

Tags: r, ubuntu, conda, gdal

In trying to install the `sf` R package, I got the error message:

```
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... no
configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0
```

I then installed `gdal` 2.3.1 [from conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal) and confirmed the version:

```
gdalinfo --version
```

> GDAL 2.3.1, released 2018/06/22

But I still get the same error message.

[SF on R 3.5 can't find correct version of gdal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210587/sf-on-r-3-5-cant-find-correct-version-of-gdal) looks similar but their solution involved installing outside of conda. I'm on Ubuntu.

How can I get `sf` to recognize the correct version of `gdal` I have installed?

Edit: `sessionInfo()` in `R` shows:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1
```

I had another issue when installing R from conda

Edit: When installing R from conda via `conda install -c r r`, I got this error:

```
-----Error: libudunits2.a not found-----
     If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location,
     use --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib' for example,
     or --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
     replacing paths with appropriate values for your installation.
     You can alternatively use the UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIB
     environment variables.
     If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.
     It is required for this package.
```

This was still the case after installing `udunits` and `udunits2` from conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge udunits
conda install -c conda-forge udunits2
```

Comment: You could try installing R from conda as well.

Comment: @Ista I did that before and had some other error, so went with CRAN, but I'm retrying and will edit with an update.

Comment: @ista updated with the separate issue when installing R from conda, concerning udunits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are caused by non-conda package installations. From a clean environment, the `sf` package can be installed [directly from `conda`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-sf):

```
conda create -n rsf -c conda-forge r-sf
source activate rsf
```

Or from a clean environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-sf
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me, though I ran it on Centos 6 rather than Ubuntu 16.04.

```
conda create -n rsf r-udunits2 geos gdal proj4
source activate rsf
R
```

.

```
install.packages("sf")
library("sf")
```

Comment: Worked without the `goes`, thank you! When I do it in my default environment, I get an error message like http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Problems-with-installing-rgdal-on-Ubuntu-quot-checking-gdal-linking-with-libs-only-no-quot-td7590255.html, so it seems like my GDAL installation is broken. I'll try uninstalling some gdal-related packages.

Comment: Sorry, goes was a typo, I meant `geos`. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

after having similar conflict issues in conda on OSX with r-sf and r-gdal i was able to get them installed with a fresh environment by installing them both immediately after initiating the new env

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-essentials geos r-rgeos r-rgdal r-sf
```